# Search a file in linux and jump to position of the first find

Tags: linux, string, file, search

I need help with a linux command with which I can search for a string in a text file and go to the first position this string is found and being able to scroll down and up from there.
I am looking for hours for such command. GREP will only find the occurrences, print them and exit the file. I need to be able to jump to that line and being able to scroll up and down in order to see the other lines around.

Comment: Do you need something that you can run directly from the command line or would it work to open the file first e.g. in vi

Comment: Your question is not clear you should try to explain how and where you are trying to use such a functionality it will help us in answering the question?

Comment: I will clarify, I am looking for some command I can run from the command line. Like LESS file.txt | grep "someword" or grep "string" file.txt but will let me stay in the open file like LESS command and scroll up and down. I hope this clears it out :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with `less` or `vim`, for example:

```
less +/pattern file.txt
vim +/pattern file.txt
```

This will open `file.txt` for editing and jump to the first match of "pattern", if such exists. You can move up or down with the arrow keys or with `j` and `k`.

The pattern can be a basic regular expression (BRE) that `less` and `vim` understand. For example:

```
less +/^settings file.txt
vim +/^settings file.txt
```

this will jump to the first line that starts with the string "settings".

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as ever.

1. Go to the file path using -> cd filepath
2. vi filename (opening the file to search)
3. /<search_word> (forward slash and no space put the word you desire to search).
4. Hit 'n' to search forwards for the next occurrence of word named “hello”. You can press N to search backwards.

Example -> /hello
jumps to the first hello printed and keep pressing n or N for forward/backward movement

If you know the time stamp somehow or unique word then you can jump directly in one shot.